# Внедрение приложения Angular на страницу

Tags: angular

Не так давно начал изучать angular, и в ходе изучения появилась идея создать  юзерскрипт, содержащий приложение, которое должно отображаться на определённой странице стороннего сайта. 
Сама страница не использует angular, и мне нужно, к примеру, заменить обычную html-форму на ней на интерфейс с поддержкой ajax. Вся проблема в том, что изменения на странице необходимо делать именно после её загрузки. Если бы я использовал простой JS, я бы сделал примерно так:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#element')[0].innerHTML = 'Мой_код_формы'
```

Но как быть с angular? Я проштудировал информацию о динамических компонентах, но проблема в том, что добавить их можно только в другие компоненты, при этом загруженная страница сама по себе компонентом не является. Следовательно, добавить какой-либо компонент на страницу с помощью ViewContainerRef я не могу.

В идеале мне нужно создать сервис, создающий необходимый компонент прямо в нужном месте в "сыром" DOM (например, в DIV с нужным id), так как планируется множество различных компонентов. Есть ли такая возможность в принципе, и если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: чтобы заменить даже обычную форму на форму из angular - нужно тянуть за собой все исходники, т.е. `@angular/(core|common)` и скомпилированные компоненты/пайпы/директивы, из этого следует вопрос надо ли оно вам?

Comment: Форма была озвучена как пример. На деле я собираюсь полностью переделать интерфейс, сделав из него почти-SPA. Вдобавок, это отличная и нетривиальная практика. Поэтому да, всё-таки нужно :)

Comment: > "Форма была озвучена как пример" - неважно, что было озвучено, ответ будет один и тот же что бы вы не пытались реализовать, еще есть `@angular/elements`, но очень сырой еще

Comment: Правильно ли я понял вас, что реализация такой идеи с помощью angular невозможна?

Comment: возможна, но придется копать в теорию микрофронтенда, сейчас вокруг этого большой хайп, но мало именно практической информации, в принципе `@angular/elements` может решить вашу проблему